# User input date shift in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, input

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like a user to input an integer that will shift specific dates for a given condition.

**Data**

```
         start      m1          m2          de          re          type
0       2018-01-01  2022-01-01  2022-04-01  2022-05-01  2022-06-01  aa
1       2018-01-01  2022-01-01  2022-04-01  2022-05-01  2022-06-01  aa
2       2018-01-01  2022-01-01  2022-04-01  2022-05-01  2022-06-01  bb
```

**Desired**

```
     **User input**: 9

        start       m1          m2          de          re          type
0       2018-01-01  2022-10-01  2023-01-01  2023-02-01  2023-03-01  aa
1       2018-01-01  2022-10-01  2023-01-01  2023-02-01  2023-03-01  aa
2       2018-01-01  2022-10-01  2023-01-01  2022-05-01  2022-06-01  bb
```

#user input the integer: 9. We now add 9 to months in 'm2' column  4+9 we are now in 1/1/2023.

(04/01/2022 is in column ‘m2’. We add 9 months to this date, which gives us 1/1/2023)

**Doing**

```py
month_value = df["m2"] += pd.DateOffset(months=int(input()))
       
if df[type] == 'aa':  # condition applied
    d = {
      'm1': pd.DateOffset(months=3),  #we offset m1, 3 months from m2
      'de': pd.DateOffset(months=1),
      're': pd.DateOffset(months=2),
    }
        
    s = pd.Series(d).rsub(month_value)
    df.assign(**{**s, 'm2': month_value})
   
else:
    e = {'m1': pd.DateOffset(months=3),}
    s1 = pd.Series(e).rsub(month_value)
    df.assign(**{**s1, 'm2': month_value})
```

I am researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Try numpy where ?

Comment: @BENY will try to incorporate numpy - you mean for the conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lambda function for that:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'m1': [pd.Timestamp('2022-10-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-10-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-10-01')], 
                   'm2': [pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01')],  
                   'de': [pd.Timestamp('2023-02-01'), pd.Timestamp('2023-02-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-05-01')],   
                   're': [pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01'), pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-06-01')], 
                   'type': ['aa', 'aa', 'bb']})

df["m2"] += pd.DateOffset(months=int(input('Offset: ')))

# Shift the dependent columns m1, de, re when type is 'aa'
df[df.type == 'aa'] = df[df.type == 'aa'].assign(m1 = lambda row: row['m2'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3))
df[df.type == 'aa'] = df[df.type == 'aa'].assign(de = lambda row: row['m2'] + pd.DateOffset(months=1))
df[df.type == 'aa'] = df[df.type == 'aa'].assign(re = lambda row: row['m2'] + pd.DateOffset(months=2))

# Shift only m1 when type is not 'aa'
df[df.type != 'aa'] = df[df.type != 'aa'].assign(m1 = lambda row: row['m2'] - pd.DateOffset(months=3))

print(df)
```

Comment: Ok shouldn’t m2 column be 01/01/2023 ? And would like to have remaining columns. Will try thank you

Comment: In the example I have used offset=4. Please note that my snippet is a stub. Since I dont have your original dataset, I have recreated a new one including m1, m2, and type only. Don't worry, if you have additional columns, the lambda function will not affect them!

Comment: I see - will try. Not sure the above solution takes into account the other shifts though within the dictionaries d and e?

Comment: No, but it is on purpose for the sake of simplicity. To shift the other columns just copy/paste the same line but replace all the "m2" in the assing() with "de" and "re", "m1" or whatever you prefer

Comment: I see, the shift will be based off of the input for ‘m2’ in particular. (The other columns shift based on m2 input) Will that still work? I’ll add onto it etc

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Columns m1, de and re shift dates based on the input integer from the user. (The dictionary is pointing to this) I am wondering if the above solution includes this as well. ‘m1’ shifts 3months from ‘m2’, ‘de’ shifts 1 month from ‘m2’ and ‘re’ shifts 2 months from ‘m2’. (if type == aa)

Comment: Thanks. It's more clear. I edited the answer. Now it returns the output you provided when offset=9

Comment: Oh I see this appears to work- I will try. So you applying them independently ok. I understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use MonthOffset to add the user input month to required column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'m1': [pd.Timestamp('2022-10-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-10-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-10-01')], 
                   'm2': [pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01')], 
                   'type': ['aa', 'aa', 'bb']})    

user_input = 9
df['m2'] = df['m2'] + pd.offsets.MonthOffset(user_input)
```

You get

```
    m1          m2          type
0   2022-10-01  2023-01-01  aa
1   2022-10-01  2023-01-01  aa
2   2022-10-01  2023-01-01  bb
```

Comment: Thank you yes, but need to apply the shifts on remaining columns.